# Unity VideoPlayer with Subtitles

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was going to use the VideoPlayer to render to Camera Near Plane, but I also want to display subtitles for the video for the sake of accessibility. I'm wondering what the best way to do that is.

I can't see anything on a canvas if I render to Near Plane. I'd like the video to appear in front of the scene so that I can have the scene there once the video is complete.

Do I need to be using a render texture to achieve this? Seems like a render texture might incur some unnecessary overhead for my purposes, but I could be wrong.

The idea is this:

Far Background - Scene
Background - Black Image (so i can fade to scene)
Middleground - Video
Foreground - Subtitles

More info:
This is a 2D point and click adventure game with a pre-rendered cutscene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert Mocks's answer is perfectly tenable and makes sense to me.  Thank you for that!

What I decided to do instead was use a RawImage so that I wouldn't have to deal with extra cameras.  This way I can use the canvas as I normally would and don't have to deal with render textures.

This involves using the API Only setting along with the following code:

```
rawImage.texture = videoPlayer.texture;
```

That seems to work well for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a render texture, place it in front of the camera at an exact distance and size, but I wouldn't. Probably would be a different camera anyway for lighting or clipping purposes.

I would use a second Camera, rendering over top of the Main Camera, with the subtitle UI's canvas targeting the second camera's screen space, and clearing depth only. It will render what it sees, but with a totally transparent background. Then, you can render your video on either the main camera's near plane or the new subtitle camera's far plane.

You could put your black square in front of this camera, too, though it would be in front of the video. It could be UI on the main camera, or stick a third camera in between them. You might have to worry about performance if there are too many cameras, but I have used two or three before to no noticeable performance hit.